# How to run Test Analyze Code Coverage for all test and exclude some specific projects in visual studio 2012?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

Currently in Visual Studio 2012, when getting code coverage for all of unit tests, I go for TEST - Analayze Code Coverage - All Tests as below snapshoot.

That will get code coverage for all projects in my solution which also include my unit test project(s).

I want to get rid of some specific projects such as those unit testing ones.. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a .runsettings file to the solution and configure Visual Studio to use that. There is no editor, designer or intellisense for this file, but it's pretty well documented here:

> [Configuring Unit Tests by using a .runsettings File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx)

For changing Code Coverage the following section is what you're after::

```
  <!-- Configurations for data collectors -->
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <ModulePaths>
              <Exclude>
                <ModulePath>.*CPPUnitTestFramework.*</ModulePath>
              </Exclude>
            </ModulePaths>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>

    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
```